# "Invalid Tilemap Layer ID: walls" error on phaser-framework when creating a static layer

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm working on a game, and have made a map in Tiled which i was trying to render. I got the following error when trying to create a static layer using `createStaticLayer()`:

> Invalid Tilemap Layer ID: walls

I checked the name, but it is correct. The json file itself loads properly, and everything the documentation told me to pay attention to is fine, yet the error continues to be thrown.

```
function preload () {
  this.load.setBaseURL('http://127.0.0.1:3000/asset?file=');
  this.load.image('sky', 'assets/images/space.png');
  //this.load.image('ground', 'assets/images/platform.png')
  this.load.image('star', 'assets/images/star.png');
  //this.load.image('tile', 'assets/images/tile.png');
  this.load.image('tile_set', 'assets/tilesets/tileset_cc_1.png');
  this.load.tilemapTiledJSON("map_cc", "assets/maps/test_map_cc.json")
}

function create () {
  this.add.image(960, 540, 'sky');
  //map, tilesets
  let map = this.make.tilemap("map_cc");
  let cc = map.addTilesetImage("cc", "tile_set");
  //layers
  let wall = map.createStaticLayer("walls", [cc], 0, 0);
}
```

Is there something i'm missing that no question here has had an answer to yet? i'm completely lost and have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Would you be able to put together an example of this, perhaps a github repo or something. It's hard to debug just from this.

Comment: In addition to verifying the layer name is correct, have you also verified the tileset name provided to `map.addTilesetImage()` matches what you've specified in Tiled?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but if someone else is having a similar problem:

When making the tilemap, make sure to make it like this:

```
this.make.tilemap({key: 'map_cc'});
```

This way, it should load you map correctly